# Make a HTML counter that relays stats from an address on Etherscan

Tags: web3js

I'm a new dev and I have a pretty noob question so please go easy on me :)

I'm trying to make a counter on my website that shows some stats about my Dice smart contract. I want it to include how many bets it has, largest bet, profit etc. Similar to what vdice has on their website: https://vdice.io

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to implement this:

---

#### Have these values available in the contract

If your contract already computes these values and saves them in the state you can create getters for these and have them available.

The downside to this method is that it becomes more expensive to use your contract because of the additional computation needed to update the values.

---

#### Save these values in an external service that monitors the blockchain

Create a different service that monitors your smart contract and computes these values. Your web interface will connect to this API and request and display the data.

The downside to this method is that the service might get out of sync with the blockchain, thus a rescrape would be needed.

---

#### Monitor the blockchain in the browser

This is similar to the version above, just that there is no previous state to start from. You can monitor the blockchain from the moment the user opened your website and start saving the computed metrics.

I am suggesting to start from the moment the user opens the website (from that block) and not from the moment the contract was deployed because pretty quickly it will become very slow to process everything (considering there's a new block generated every 15 seconds)

The downside to this method is that it's very computationally expensive to scrape the full smart contract data.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
Do you think its possible to do this through etherscan directly?